# How to find the inverse of f?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, inverse

$ f : A \rightarrow B $ where $ A = B = \left \{4,5,6,7  \right \} $

$ f = \left \{ (4,6),(5,5),(6,7),(7,5) \right \} $

Find $ f^{-1} $

---

I know how to find the inverse of $ f $ if it were something like $ f(x) = 2x + 3 $ by finding $ f(y) = x $...
How should I approach this problem?

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: Shouldn't it be the same since the domain of $f$ is the same as the co-domain of $f$?

Comment: Hint: The inverse of the function {(1,2)} is {(2,1)}

Comment: The inverse does not exist in this case. Note that $5$ and $7$ get mapped to $5$ (so $f$ is not one-to-one).

Comment: @Cameron-Williams How is not one to one for 5 and 7? Where are you getting those numbers? From $ f $ or $ f:A \rightarrow B $ ?

Comment: $f: 4 \rightarrow 6 \rightarrow 7 \rightarrow 5 \rightarrow 5$.

$A = \{4, 5, 6, 7 \}$. 

Pick a point $y$ in $A$ and ask yourself what number $x$ do you feed into $f$ in order to get $y$? 

Say you pick $y = 5$, then $x = 7$ works because $f: 7 \rightarrow 5$ and you can do the rest similarly. In this case, $f^{-1}(A) = \{5, 6, 7\}$

Comment: @tommark The way you should think about the ordered pairs is that $(4,6)$ means that $f(4) = 6$, $(5,5)$ means $f(5) = 5$, $(6,7)$ means $f(6) = 7$ and $(7,5)$ means $f(7) = 5$. Notice that $f(5) = 5 = f(7)$. The ordered pairs are just a way of associating the variable with its value under $f$.

Comment: I see! Thanks! So because it's not one-to-one it cannot be invertible.

Comment: @tommark exactly right :)

Answer (score 1):

$f : A \rightarrow B $, where

$\begin{cases}
A = B = \{4,5,6,7 \} \\
f = \{ (4,6),(5,5),(6,7),(7,5)\} 
\end{cases}$

is a function $f\subset A\times B$, while $f^{-1}\subset B\times A$ is the relation
$f^{-1} = \{ (6,4),(5,5),(7,6),(5,7)\}$ where all the $(x,y)$ is reversed to $(y,x)$. Since both $(5,5),(5,7)\in f^{-1}$ the relation $f^{-1}$ can't be a function.